# Mock a method without mocking a class first

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, moq

I am using moq4 for mocking things in my **UnitTests**. I have a class say **TestClass** in which a method called **TestMethod** is their that i wanted to test.
So my problem is my **TestMethod** requires a check on **testlist** that is in my TestClass. Like this:-

```
public Class TestClass
{    
    public readonly ISomeService _someService;

    public bool TestProperty { get; private set; }

    public List<string> testlist { get; private set; }

    Public TestClass(ISomeService someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
    }

    public async Task<bool> TestMethod(string sd)
    {
      if(TestProperty) // here how can i control this property in UnitTest.
         return false; 

      testlist.contains(sd); // check in this list but list will be null.
    }

    public async Task<List<string>> SetTestListAndProperty()
    {
        testlist.Add("2");
        testlist.Add("3");

        TestProperty = false;
    } 

}
```

Now in **testmethodtests i have mocked the ISomeService and passed to TestClass constructor**.

```
var someservicemock = new Mock<ISomeService>();

var testclassobj = new TestClass(someservicemock.Object);
```

**Now i called My TestMethod**

```
result = await testclassobj.TestMethod("id"); // it is throwing the exception that testlist is null.
```

// I am also wanted to test the TestMethod when TestProperty Is false. So how can i set this property it does not have public setter. And it is being set by other methd(**SetTestListAndProperty**).

So my question is can i mock the TestClass **testlist** without mocking the TestClass ?
If this way is wrong please let me know, or you know any workaround then also.
cheers

Comment: How does `testlist` ever get set? In the code sample you posted it's impossible to set outside of the class and is not set inside the class.

Comment: it is going to be set in some method from inside. So is it right to call other methods to test some method ?

Comment: It's difficult to know what it is exactly that you're trying to test from the code you have above. As has already been pointed out, `testlist` is never initialized so the only result you'll ever get from calling `TestMethod` is a `NullReferenceException.`

`testlist` looks to be an implementation detail of `TestClass` so doesn't look like it should be tested directly. If you can show more of the code though, perhaps we can help further.

Comment: @RussCam can you look at it now. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question boils down to: what to do when the *method under test* depends on internal state that is set by *some other method*?

Here's an example:

```
class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private List<T> _list = new List<T>();
    private Receiver _receiver;

    public MyCollection()
    {
        _receiver = receiver;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    public void RemoveAndNotify(T item)
    {
        _list.Remove(item);
        _receiver.Notify(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

(by the way, calling your types `TestClass`, `TestProperty` and `testlist` doesn't really help - the reader has no idea how these things relate to each other. It's amost as confusing as the darned Foo, Bar and Baz. Use cats, dogs, people, etc, concrete and meaningful names instead.)

1. So, say you want to unit test the `RemoveAndNotify` method. But you can't remove an item without adding one first! 
   Does this mean I have to mock the internal `_list` to insert dummy data? NO!
2. Also, how do I verify that the item has indeed been removed from the internal list? Do I have to somehow retrieve the internal _list and check its contents (through injection, reflection, etc)? NO!

I think the crux of your issue is: a unit test doesn't necessarily test *one method*!
A unit test tests the smallest possible unit of *behaviour*.

That unit of behaviour may involve calling one *or more* methods. So here's how I would unit test the behaviour related to removing items.
There's two *behaviours* we want to test.

1. We want to test that the collection no longer has an item after we've removed it.
2. We want to test that the receiver gets notified when an item is removed.

```
[Fact]
public void RemoveAndNotify_RemovesItem()
{   
    //Arrange
    var mockReceiver = ...
    var collection = new MyCollection<int>(mockReceiver.Object);

    collection.Add(5);

    //Act
    collection.Remove(5);

    //Assert
    //internally calls GetEnumerator to verify that the collection no longer contains "5"
    Assert.AreEqual(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), collection); 
}


[Fact]
public void RemoveAndNotify_NotifiesReceiver()
{   
    //Arrange
    var mockReceiver = ...
    var collection = new MyCollection<int>(mockReceiver.Object);

    collection.Add(5);

    //Act
    collection.Remove(5);

    //Assert
    mockReceiver.Verify(rec => rec.Notify(5), Times.Once());
}
```

As you can see, the first unit test called *three* methods on the class (`Add`, `Remove` and `GetEnumerator`) in order to test *one unit of behaviour*.

Bottom line: forget about "methods under test", and think about "behaviour under test". You're testing behaviours, not methods.

Comment: Thanks actually "Bottom line" is the key point that i am missing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually i am just don't want use other methods for testing a method. now i got it.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. I wouldn't recommend to mock *everything* you can. In case of collections it is totally okay, to use real (not mocked) objects. Where is the benefit when you mock the list? You can very easily test just everything by examining the `testlist` property.
2. (This is a side note, but also addresses your first comment.) Try to make your types immutable. You can find numerous articles about this topic. Just search for it. The benefit is that you don't have to deal with `NullReferenceException`s and a bunch of other scenarios. For your example this means, that you should initialize `testlist` in the constructor.

Comment: How can i set some data to testlist ? in my case.

Comment: You mean initializing the list?

Comment: nope i can initialize that list in the constructore how can i fill some string items from my testmethod.

Comment: `obj.testlist.Add(item)` or what do you mean?

Comment: OMG how can i miss it. I think i am really tired to work now. Thanks Matthias.

Comment: but what about a Simple Variable Property that does not have public setter ?

Comment: (Forget my previous comment) Can you explain your problem more detailed? Do you have problems with testing these properties?

Comment: Thanks. I can't make that a Tick that answer Right. +1 is i think not bad :) thanks for help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56185/discussion-between-loop-and-matthias).

Answer (score 0):

I would create another constructor that takes the list as a parameter so you can create and populate a list with test data, in your test, and then give it to the class under test.

```
public TestClass(ISomeService service, IList<string> list) {
    _someService = service;
    testList = list;
}
```

Using this constructor, testList wont be null unless you pass null in.

I know some don't like to add methods only used for tests. If you don't want to expose another constructor that will only be used for tests you can mark the new constructor `internal` and expose internals only to your test assembly.

```
internal TestClass(ISomeService service, IList<string> list) {
    ...
}
```

In the project's `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("your test assembly");
```

Edit: For the properties. If you have properties that don't expose setters, you can mark the properties `virtual` and use Moq's `SetupGet` method to setup the properties return value.

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
    public virtual string TestProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

In your test:

```
public void SomeTest() {
    var mock = new Mock<ClassUnderTest>();
    mock.SetupGet(m => m.TestProperty).Returns("hi");

    var result = mock.Object.TestProperty;

    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("hi"); // should pass
}
```

Comment: but what about a Simple Variable Property that does not have public setter ? their are several properties like this then ?

Comment: With enough of them, I would think of faking the class and publicly exposing the setters.

Comment: Can't i make the Class under test a mock ?

Comment: Check my edit. You can mrk  those properties as `virtual` and setup the value the properties getter will return.