# How to mock a method called inside another method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I would like to explain my problem using an example.

```cs
class A
{
    Fun1()
    {
        // some code
        B obj2 = new B();
        obj2.Fun2();
    }
}

class B
{
    Fun2() 
    {
        // some code
    }
}

// Test class for Class A
class A_Test
{
    public Fun1_Test()
    {
        A obj1 = new A();
        A.Fun1();
    }
}
```

Here I am calling `Fun1` which calls `Fun2()`. I want to mock call to `Fun2()`.

I need to do the initialization of Class B object in `Fun1()` only, I don't want to do it using the constructor.

It is possible to mock call to `Fun2()`?

Comment: Don't use direct dependencies use dependency injection. and it would be better if you read SOLID principles first.

Comment: For mock class B you must pass mock implementation of it to class A. By your way you can't do it. It's one reason of using interfaces instead of specific implementations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't, because `Fun2` is an instance method of an object created *inside* `Fun1`.

Since `A` depends on `B`, `B` should be injected into `A`, if you want to achieve true isolation.

You should also "Depend upon abstractions", as advertised by the Dependency Inversion Principle. Make `B` implement an interface `IB`, and make `A` depend on `IB` instead. Then, you mock the interface `IB` and inject that mock instead.

```cs
class A
{
    public Fun1(IB ib) { ib.Fun2(); }
}

interface IB
{
    Fun2();
}

class B : IB
{
    public Fun2() {}
}

// Test class for Class A
class A_Test
{
    public Fun1_Test()
    {
        var bMock = new Mock<IB>();
        bMock.Setup(b => b.Fun2());

        A obj1 = new A();
        A.Fun1(bMock.Object);
    }
}
```

Read:

1. [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)
2. [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: It Would be better if you use interfaces in this example.

Comment: @loop Yeah, I deleted the *other* suggestion as it might encourage the reader to take the fastest path instead of the correct path.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion. But unfortunately I am not allowed to make changes in that piece of code, although I need to write a Test Method for it. Is there is any other way to test Fun1()?

Comment: @dcastro can you look at one of my ques,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373600/mock-a-method-without-mocking-a-class-first i am new to UnitTesting.

Comment: @Atul Sorry, no. The code is flawed, there's strong dependencies between `A` and `B` which make the code impossible to unit test, and will be hard to maintain in the future. It *must* be changed.

Comment: Also, did you not write this code yourself? As a side note, this is one of the many reasons why the author of a piece of code should be the one unit testing it. That's also why Agile/XP preach *collective code ownership*.

Answer (score 4):

Classic example which shows how if you cannot unit test a particular component, REFACTOR the component!

This is where is love what any mocking framework enforces you to do - write decoupled code.

In your example, the class A is very tightly coupled with the concrete implementation of B. You could decouple it using (like most of the answers suggest) dependency injection. By doing so, you would end up depending on the IB abstraction than any concrete implementation of it.